# Vue slot component doesn't hot reload when data() is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I have a Vue component inside another component (using slots). I have some `data()` on the slot component but when I change the `data()` (*for example:* `name: "John"` ***to*** `name: "Steve"`) then press save, the component doesn't hot reload the change — it requires a manual refresh to see the changes.

However, if I change some normal text in the html `<template>` section of the slot component (*for example:* `<div class="foo">Foo</div>` ***to*** `<div class="bar">Bar</div>`) then press save, the component hot reloads and the changes are instantly made in the browser. Is this normal? I thought Vue was reactive to everything that affects the "view"? Or am I just being a complete idiot here?

I made a simple example [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cookies-uz6tq?file=/src/App.vue) so you can see what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: Does this only happen on codesandbox? What about a local webpack/vue-cli dev server?

Comment: Happens on localhost too. At first I thought it was a problem with the setup/config on my local machine, but seeing it happen on codesandbox confirmed to me that it was a Vue issue.

Comment: Another example: Try changing the `msg` property in `data()` to `whatever` but leave `{{msg}}` in the html template and then press save. The browser still renders the `{{msg}}` template data even though the `msg` property no longer exists!

Comment: Update: Doing all of the above **without using slots** completely solves the problem and components are hot-reloaded as expected. So ***now*** the question is why doesn't this work when I use slots?